# Getting CORS Errors with Splunk

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, splunk

I am trying to write data to Splunk with a jQuery script running in a browser. I already have the following in my 'inputs.conf' file:

```
crossOriginSharingPolicy = *
```

However, the error I'm getting is:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myserver.myco.com:8088/services/collector/event.  
(Reason: missing token 'content-type' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).
```

I have not found a way to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from Splunk.

Here is a snippet of the JS code, although I'm not sure it is even necessary to show it (the commented lines are things I tried in desperation, but they made no difference):

```
    var dfr = $.ajax({
        url: config.endpoint,
        method: 'post',
//      headers: {
//          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
//          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
//          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
//      },
//      crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", header);
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({ event: post }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Any suggestions? Do I need to access Splunk via a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set `contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and format your data as that (that is, basically just like a normal query string: name-value pairs with the name followed by `=` and then the value, with the name-value pairs separated from each other by `&`).

That’s because it seems Splunk doesn’t support `application/json` requests at all.

[Discussion elsewhere](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-javascript-logging/issues/9#issuecomment-252770795) indicates it expects `POSTs` to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But that’d only fix the `content-type` problem. Because your request sends an `Authorization` request header, that will also on its own trigger a trigger a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

And if the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header Splunk sends back doesn’t include `Authorization`, then you’re gonna run into the same problem you had with `Content-Type`.

Dunno though, maybe behind the scenes Splunk already includes `Authorization` in the set of header names it sends back in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header.